# Lenovo T410 laptop and dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have my laptop on a mini dock with an external monitor connected to the VGA port on the dock.  I would like to connect a second monitor for extended desktop sharing, but don't have DVI ports on the dock (read about it on other posts) - looks like I only have 1 VGA port on the dock, and one available on the laptop itself.  Can I connect my second monitor to the VGA port on the laptop while it's connected to the dock and use both monitors?

If not, is there another solution to being able to use dual monitors with this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

> If not, is there another solution to being able to use dual monitors with this configuration?

You can always add an external GPU to your system. Low performance versions have enough bandwidth from an USB port. (low performance as in: useless for gaming, but just fine to display a spreadsheet, read email, etc etc).